# Programmatically setting Image.Source property: I get an empty image

Tags: c#, wpf, image

I have a folder inside my project which includes some images, for example: "Cards/1-1.png".

I have an Image element linked with XAML, and I'm trying to set it's `Source` property programmatically:

```
BitmapImage bitmap = new BitmapImage();
string filename= "Cards/1-1.png";
bitmap.UriSource = new Uri("/Poker;component/" + filename, UriKind.Relative);
cardImage1.Source= bitmap;  // myImage linked with XAML
```

I try to fill 5 images, and I checked the filenames, they're correct. But the images are still empty (they're inside the StackPanel on the right):

```
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" DockPanel.Dock="Right"
        Background="Green">
        <Image Width="80" Height="100" Margin="10" x:Name="cardImage1"/>
        <Image Width="80" Height="100" Margin="10" x:Name="cardImage2"/>
        <Image Width="80" Height="100" Margin="10" x:Name="cardImage3"/>
        <Image Width="80" Height="100" Margin="10" x:Name="cardImage4"/>
        <Image Width="80" Height="100" Margin="10" x:Name="cardImage5"/>
    </StackPanel>
```

[image]

Comment: Just try with one image and see whether it works...and also take out the background color of the Stackpanel and check.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[**BitmapImage**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms619218) implements [**ISupportInitialize**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.isupportinitialize.aspx) interface which means any property change after initialization of object will be ignored unless wrap in **`BeginInit()`** and **`EndInit()`**.

Quote from **MSDN**:

> BitmapImage implements the ISupportInitialize interface to optimize
>   initialization on multiple properties. Property changes can only occur
>   during object initialization. Call BeginInit to signal that
>   initialization has begun and EndInit to signal that initialization has
>   completed. After initialization, property changes are ignored.
>
> BitmapImage objects created using the BitmapImage constructor are
>   automatically initialized and property changes are ignored.

So, change your code to wrap property initialization like this:

```
BitmapImage bitmap = new BitmapImage();
string filename= "Cards/1-1.png";
bitmap.BeginInit();
bitmap.UriSource = new Uri("/Poker;component/" + filename, UriKind.Relative);
bitmap.EndInit();
cardImage1.Source= bitmap;  // myImage linked with XAML
```

OR

Initialize all relevant properties at time of initialization by passing Uri in constructor like this:

```
string filename= "Cards/1-1.png";
BitmapImage bitmap = new BitmapImage(new Uri("/Poker;component/" + filename, 
                                              UriKind.Relative));
```

Answer (score 1):

I tried this code but it isn't working, i found a way to do what you exactly need:

```
cardImage1.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("/Poker;component/" + filename, UriKind.Relative));
```

you assigned BitmapImage.Source to Image.Source, i think that's why it isn't working.

Hope it helps.